# SeaFile docker container gives 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: docker

I tried following the official seafile docker instructions at https://github.com/haiwen/seafile-docker/blob/master/README.md

I used the following docker command:

```
docker run -d --name seafile \
  -e SEAFILE_SERVER_HOSTNAME=myserver.example.com \
  -e SEAFILE_ADMIN_EMAIL=admin \
  -e SEAFILE_ADMIN_PASSWORD=MY_PASSWORD \
  -v /srv/seafile:/shared \
  -p 50007:80 \
  -p 50008:443 \
  seafileltd/seafile:latest
```

I also added `myserver.example.com.key` and `.crt` under `/srv/seafile/ssl`.

It seemed to run as expected. But when I point my browser to `http://myserver.example.com:50007` I get a 502 Bad Gateway error from nginx. It also seems to redirect to `http://myserver.example.com/accounts/login?next=/`.

When I try `https://myserver.example.com:50008` I get a "connection refused" error from my browser.

I also tried to use the following command:

```
docker run -d --name seafile \
  -e SEAFILE_SERVER_HOSTNAME=myserver.example.com:50007 \
  -e SEAFILE_ADMIN_EMAIL=admin \
  -e SEAFILE_ADMIN_PASSWORD=MY_PASSWORD \
  -v /srv/seafile:/shared \
  -p 50007:80 \
  -p 50008:443 \
  seafileltd/seafile:latest
```

But it made no difference, still redirecting to `http://myserver.example.com:50007`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should post your os and firewall details.

Comment: @FrontENG What about them, specifically?

Comment: What is the last lines in your "docker log <containerid>"?  I got the same error while seafile was starting.  Eventually the logs said "Seahub is started\nDone." and then I worked.

Comment: Unfortunately, once I tried downloading a file out of seafile later, it did not honor the port in my URL, instead it uses the just the servername, so it failed.